# How can I update object that contains other objects in lists with npoco?

Tags: c#, .net, npoco

I have a class with some properties with a list with other class objects inside it.

```
[TableName("tblItem")]
[PrimaryKey("ITM_Id", AutoIncrement = false)]
[ExplicitColumns]
public class Item
{
    [Column("ITM_Id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("ITM_Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<PictureLink> PictureLink { get; set; }   
}

[TableName("tblPictureLink")]
[PrimaryKey("PIL_Id", AutoIncrement = false)]
[ExplicitColumns]
public class PictureLink
{
    [Column("PIL_Id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("PIL_InformationType")]
    public string InformationType { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make an update with npoco like db.Update(Item) - but then only the properties Id and Name gets updated, how can i make the list with PictureLinks update as well in same statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the update for child objects in a loop as follows:

```
 using (var scope = db.GetTransaction())
 {
     db.Update(item);
     foreach (var pictureLink in item.PictureLinks)
     {
         db.Update(pictureLink);
     }
     scope.Complete();
  }
```

Enclosing the update in a transaction will ensure a rollback if anything goes wrong.